# Insert fields in all documents of a mongo collection where value of the new field is the value of another field of the same document

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

My collection looks something like this:-

customer_collection:-

```json
{"_id" : "507f191e810c19239de098db", "name" : "John", [other data]}
{"_id" : "507f191e810c19729de860ea", "name" : "Dave", [other data]}
```

I want to add two more fields, *nickname* and *surname*, in all documents of this collection (containing 10 million documents); setting the value of these fields to the value of *name* in this document, i.e. the altered documents should look like :-

```json
{"_id" : "507f191e810c19239de098db", "name" : "John", "nickname" : "John", "surname" : "John", [other data]}
{"_id" : "507f191e810c19729de860ea", "name" : "Dave", "nickname" : "Dave", "surname" : "Dave", [other data]}
```

How can I do this? What is the best strategy to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with the code below

```
db.customer.find().forEach( function (doc) {
  doc.nickname = doc.name; 
  doc.surname = doc.name; 
  db.customer.save(doc); 
});
```

If you are using MongoDB 3.4, you can use new $addFields aggregation pipeline operator.

Comment: I am using mongoDB 3.2

Comment: Ok then you can't use $addFields operator. Just use the code that I wrote, it will work.